# embedded youtube video wont play when floating to the right

Tags: html, css, youtube

http://www.haxxcmd.co.nf/

The above is the link to the page I am referring to.  The embedded youtube video I included does not work when floating to the right.  Removing the float lets it operate correctly, but I need it to float right.  I am a beginner with HTML/CSS.  I have researched the issue to no avail. If anybody could suggest a modification or alternate method, I am willing to listen and learn.

Comment: This was resolved easily by inspecting the element in dev tools. when you right click the video and inspect element it highlights the section to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video is being obstructed by the section to the left of it (#welcome).
You need give it a width.

```
section#welcome {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 629px;
}
```